# Are there any open source tools which can provide website performance including client rendering time

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, page-load-time

Any available open source or commercial tools for measure web application performance (page load time). One way to achieve is by implementing a methods to capture and start and end time of ui actions in automation scripts. But it won't give accurate results and takes lot of execution time on running with load.

Looking for any tools which can provide these capabilities and integration with existing UI automation scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can test client-side performance only using a real browser, for free and open source it would be combination of i.e. [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework with the performance testing tool of your choice. For example [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) can be integrated with Selenium using [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler)

A commercial tool example would be [LoadRunner](https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/loadrunner-professional/overview) with [TruClient](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/tc/en/2020/Content/TruClient/_tc_c_truclient_overview.htm) protocol.

Remember that real browsers are very resource intensive, for example [Firefox 75](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/75.0/system-requirements/) needs a CPU core and 2 GB of RAM per instance so I would recommend creating the main load on [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol level and use 1 real browser instance to check the client-side rendering performance.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. As per as I know, Jmeter doesn't give actual page rendering time. So any other alternatives??